# How to execute an .SQL script file using c# for Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to execute .SQL scripts stored in local folder into Oracle DB using C#. and so far searching for it I came across solution which are for SQL server so is there a way to execute it for Oracle DB .

Comment: You'll just need to setup the Oracle DB database driver for your project, then it should be fine to use all of the SQL server bits and bobs

Comment: @Persistence I have executed queries by writing manually in code in C# and it is working perfectly . everything is set up . I just don't know how to process queries which are stored in local folder as .SQL format. if u can help me with that

Comment: Can you not just read the file in as a string?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following to execute from Oracle:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

string oraclesqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";

FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\myscript.sql");

string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oraclesqlConnectionString);

Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```